# How to install gmic on 16.04. Error: gmic : Depends: libcurl4 but it is not installable

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to install [gmic](https://gmic.eu/download.shtml) on 16.04. I tried to follow the instructions from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/06/install-gmic-2-0-via-ppa-in-ubuntu-16-04-14-04-higher/) which explicitly mentions 16.04 but I get:

```
gmic : Depends: libcurl4 but it is not installable
```

Is there any way to install gmic on 16.04?

---

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list|grep -v \#

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @Olimjon I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine with your sources.list. But, I found that libcurl4 is not supported in Ubuntu 16.04.

So, I can think of two ways:

1) Install `libcurl3`, it is said that it will replace libcurl4:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3
```

And then try again.

2) If it does not work, then you will have to manually install `libcurl4`:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb
sudo apt remove libcurl3
sudo dpkg -i libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb
```

Note: These softwares like `php`, `cmake`, `feh`, `curl` depends `libcurl`.

If this way also does not work, you have to downgrade your version of `libcurl` to `libcurl3` (to reinstate stability). Then the only way that remains would be upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.